# unable to create tabs properly with uib-tabset

Tags: html, angularjs

I've been trying to create tabs dynamically with uib-tabset and each tab should contain different form but in my case textbox of first form gets overwritten by new tab generated (if i enter data in one form it gets replicated to other forms). I want all tabs to contain different data.

```
<uib-tabset class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
<uib-tab  role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="selectTab($index)" ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == $index}" ng-if="tab.display">
 <uib-tab-heading> 
    <a data-target="#tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.value}} <span ng-click="deleteTab($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
 </uib-tab-heading>
 <div class="panel-body" ng-if="tab.display" >
   <form ng-submit="addattributevalues()">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Regular Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input  type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="obj.regularPrice">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sale Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.salePrice" >
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Purchase Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.purchasePrice">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stock Status:</label>
       <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-white" type="submit" >Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
 </div>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: It is usually useful to specify which version of angular you're using and the head (and/or the includes) in your html.

Answer (score 1):

Below is corrected code, you need to add the model properties in the same tab object. and you have used  ng-if="tab.display" at uib-tab which is hiding all the other tabs, this should be removed.

```
<uib-tabset class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
<uib-tab  role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="selectTab($index)">
<uib-tab-heading> 
   <a href="#" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.value}} 
   <span ng-click="deleteTab($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
 </uib-tab-heading>
 <div class="panel-body">
   <form ng-submit="addattributevalues()">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Regular Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input  type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="tab.regularPrice">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sale Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tab.salePrice" >
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Purchase Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tab.purchasePrice">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stock Status:</label>
       <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-white" type="submit" >Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
 </div>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,now there is no overwriting of forms but now ng-submit has stopped working . i cant figure it out that why is this happening.

Comment: form data is not getting binded with angular's $scope variables.

Comment: try the below change

     `<form ng-submit="addattributevalues(tab)">`
and in the controller
`$scope.addattributevalues = function(tab){
};`

Answer (score 0):

I just made use uib-tabset default attributes for show hide , so we just don't require ng-click="selectTab($index)" as it is used in below line

```
<uib-tab  role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="selectTab($index)" ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == $index}" ng-if="tab.display">
```

I used `<uib-tabset active="active">` as it automatically creates the corresponding dom elements. refer below code. Also, created one plunkr for it https://plnkr.co/edit/QxcOyFir8oYS53asDlMN?p=preview

```
<uib-tabset  active="active" >
<uib-tab  role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" >

 <uib-tab-heading> 
    <a data-target="#tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.title}} <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
 </uib-tab-heading>
 <div class="panel-body">
   <form ng-submit="addattributevalues()">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Regular Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input  type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="obj.regularPrice">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sale Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.salePrice" >
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Purchase Price:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.purchasePrice">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stock Status:</label>
       <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-white" type="submit" >Submit</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Hope this solves your problem. Here, different form get different data. Data inserted in one form is not overwritten to another.

Comment: its still not working in my code , data is getting overwritten , i had made every modification u mentioned ,i cant understand why its not working.

Comment: Have you tried the plunkr link , I provided. There data is not getting overwritten. You can also try to do the unit testing first and then incorporate it in your application. Do share your plunkr or fiddle link with us so that we can look into your issue specifically.

Comment: yes i had tried that, it was not working i think maybe there was issue with dependecy in angular. anyway thanks for your help.